# Sending $_FILES information to another script using CURL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, curl, upload

I posted a file to `a.php` from the client using jQuery File Upload, but I need to forward this information to `b.php` (on a different domain than `a.php`) for further processing. How do I achieve this using CURL? Thanks!

Comment: http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To forward `$_FILES` data you need to:

1. Save the file at your server in `a.php`.
2. Send that file via POST request to `b.php`.

Code in `a.php` can look something like this:

```
$file_path = "full/path/to/upload/dir/" . basename($_FILES['my_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    $ch = curl_init('url/of/b.php'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURL_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURL_POSTFIELDS, array('my_file' => '@' . $file_path));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
} else {
    echo "Can't save file";
}
```

In `b.php` the file will be available, again, in `$_FILES['my_file']`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$filename = '/foo/bar';
$postargs = array(
  'foo' =>'bar', //normal postfield
  'fileentry' => '@'.$filename
);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURL_POSTFIELDS, $postargs);//give as array for proper encoding.
curl_exec();
```

Comment: We need this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Comment: And how do you utilize $_FILES info, like $_FILES['Filedata'] in `b.php`?